# Including survey/sampling weights into a latent profile analysis in R (preferrably with tidyLPA)?

Tags: r, statistics, data-analysis

I want to do a latent profile analysis in R with survey data. As the survey oversampled a given region I would like to adjust for that in my LPA, by including sampling weights into the analysis. I'm currently using the tidyLPA package, but would also be open for other packages.

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself:

As far as I have checked, there is currently no proper well-documented way to do this and tidyLPA does not allow for sample weights to be used. Maybe there is some possibility to perform it, when starting on the structural equation modeling level, but as it requires probably much more stat knowledge I didn't go down that road.

However the closest you will get is by making use of the mclust package and in specific the `me.weighted()` method.

I wrote a wrapper in style of tidyLPA to adjust the variances and covariances that are required and makes use of the `get_modelname()` method.

Here's the code to my mclust wrapper:

```
mclust_weighted = function(data,weight,nrClusters,variance,covariance) {
  modelname = get_modelname(variance,covariance)
  print('doing pre-fit')  
  fit = Mclust(data,nrClusters,modelNames = modelname)

  print('doing weighted-fit')
  re_fit = do.call("me.weighted",c(list(weights = weight),fit))

  return(re_fit)
}
```

Here's the `get_modelname()` method from tidylpa:

```
get_modelname <- function(variances, covariances){
  number = ((which(c("zero", "equal", "varying") == covariances)-1)*2)+which(c("equal", "varying") == variances)
  if(any(number %in% c(4, 5))) stop("Mclust does not allow for models with ", paste(tolower(get_title(number[which(number %in% c(4, 5))])), collapse = ", or "),".", call. = FALSE)
  c("EEI", "VVI", "EEE", "4", "5", "VVV")[number]
}
```

And here's the documentation/paper from the me.weighted() method:
https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=688c95ddadbec43fca74cfa557039f265cc6a254

Comment: For python maybe just use the scikit learn library: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html